# SQL Pivot Multiple Rows and Columns to Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that pivots multiple rows and columns into a single easy to read columns.  This is what the source data looks like.

| Time | Source | Temp1 | Temp 2 | Temp 3 | Temp 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 1 | 3 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 |
| 1 | 4 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 |

This is what I want

| Time | Src1_Temp1 | Src1_Temp 2 | Src1_Temp 3 | Src1_Temp 4 | Src2_Temp1 | Src2_Temp 2 | Src2_Temp 3 | Src2_Temp 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 20 | 21 | 21 | 23 |

I am attempting to use a Pivot in SQL, however, I am having a hard time defining multiple aggregates within the pivot

```
Select Time,
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
FROM 
(
  SELECT Source
      , Time
      ,Temp1
      ,Temp2
      ,Temp2
      ,Temp3
  FROM MySourceTable
  group by Time, Source, Temp1, Temp2, Temp3, Temp4
) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Temp1) 
    FOR Source in ([1] Src1, [2] Src2, [3] Src3, [4] Src4)  
) as Pivot
```

The issue I have is, I cannot select  Max(Temp1), Max(Temp2), Max(Temp3), Max(Temp4) in the PIVOT.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This looks like product-specific sql

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: It does not.  That is using dynamic sql and is taking mutliple rows with a single column of data.  I have multiple Rows and Multiple columns

Comment: This was literally answered like 5 questions ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76289239/convert-column-value-data-to-row-value-data-in-sql

Comment: But it really wasnt.  If you look at the answer, it is only pivoting one column from the source table.  Even the Dynamic SQL is pulling 1 column.  I am asking how i can pull multiple columns from the source table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `UNPIVOT` your data, then it becomes a small matter to PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select A.Time
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values ( concat('Src',source,'_Temp 1'),[Temp 1])
                             ,( concat('Src',source,'_Temp 2'),[Temp 2])
                             ,( concat('Src',source,'_Temp 3'),[Temp 3])
                             ,( concat('Src',source,'_Temp 4'),[Temp 4])
                     ) B(Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(value) for Item in (
                                    [Src1_Temp 1],
                                    [Src1_Temp 2],
                                    [Src1_Temp 3],
                                    [Src1_Temp 4],
                                    [Src2_Temp 1],
                                    [Src2_Temp 2],
                                    [Src2_Temp 3],
                                    [Src2_Temp 4],
                                    [Src3_Temp 1],
                                    [Src3_Temp 2],
                                    [Src3_Temp 3],
                                    [Src3_Temp 4],
                                    [Src4_Temp 1],
                                    [Src4_Temp 2],
                                    [Src4_Temp 3],
                                    [Src4_Temp 4]
                                ) ) src
```

**Results**

[image]